# Alamofire not failing when airplane mode is on

Tags: ios, xcode, download, swift3, alamofire

I'm developing an iOS download app, that uses Alamofire 4.4 and Swift 3.0.

The app gets a url and downloads the file using Alamofire.
I'm using the background session manager so that the app can download whilst in the background and send a notification when complete.

For some reason, after adding this, the .failure response is never triggered even when putting airplane mode on.
If it turn airplane mode back off, the download weirdly continues going, but leave it long enough and it doesn't continue downloading, so you'd imagine it would have triggered the failure...

I have this code for the download request:

```
    if let resumeData = resumeData {
        request = BackendAPIManager.sharedInstance.alamoFireManager.download(resumingWith: resumeData, to: destination)
    }
    else {
        request = BackendAPIManager.sharedInstance.alamoFireManager.download(extUrl, to: destination)
    }

    alamoRequest = request
        .responseData { response in

            switch response.result {
            case .success:

                //get file path of downloaded file
                let filePath = response.destinationURL?.path

                completeDownload(filePath: filePath!)

            case .failure:

                //this is what never calls on network drop out
                print("Failed")

            }

        .downloadProgress { progress in

            let progressPercent = Float(progress.fractionCompleted)

            //handle other progress stuff

        }
    }
```

.success case triggers fine, and progress returns fine.
If I cancel a download with alamoRequest?.cancel() then it does trigger the .failure case.

Here's my completion handler:

```
class BackendAPIManager: NSObject {
    static let sharedInstance = BackendAPIManager()

    var alamoFireManager : Alamofire.SessionManager!

    var backgroundCompletionHandler: (() -> Void)? {
        get {
            return alamoFireManager?.backgroundCompletionHandler
        }
        set {
            alamoFireManager?.backgroundCompletionHandler = newValue
        }
    }

    fileprivate override init()
    {
        let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.background(withIdentifier: "com.uniqudeidexample.background")
        self.alamoFireManager = Alamofire.SessionManager(configuration: configuration)
    }
}
```

And in my AppDelegate:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession identifier: String, completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

    BackendAPIManager.sharedInstance.backgroundCompletionHandler = completionHandler

    //do other notification stuff...
}
```

Before I added the background session stuff it worked ok, and when I activated airplane mode it failed. So am I missing something?

Hope that all makes sense, it's my first app, so not clued up on all the technicalities,

Thanks

Comment: Did you find any solution?